# IE 10 $digest() iteration reached using fallback html5 mode (angularjs)

Tags: html, url-rewriting, angularjs, internet-explorer-10

From the documentation of $location

> Fallback for legacy browsers For browsers that support the HTML5
>   history API, $location uses the HTML5 history API to write path and
>   search. If the history API is not supported by a browser, $location
>   supplies a Hasbang URL. This frees you from having to worry about
>   whether the browser viewing your app supports the history API or not;
>   the $location service makes this transparent to you.

It works fine under FF,Chrome and IE10 (whatever the browser mode). However when I try to test in less than IE9 mode, the fallback mode with hashbang behaves oddly. The window location is converted as expected

```
http://myserver.net/#!/thewebapp
```

it displays the server root content since angularjs fails during the rendering.

```
SCRIPT5022: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

After reading other Q/A, I suspect IE10 can't be used this way. Another source is maybe the server side rewriting or a combination of both. Right now I have no clue.